# How does this function to remove duplicate characters from a string in python work?

Tags: python

I was looking up how to create a function that removes duplicate characters from a string in python and found this on stack overflow:

```
    from collections import OrderedDict

    def remove_duplicates (foo) :
        print " ".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(foo))
```

It works, but how? I've searched what OrderedDict and fromkeys mean but I can't find anything that explains how it works in this context.

Comment: Note that this method isn't very fast

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I will give it a shot:

[OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) are dictionaries that store keys in order they are added. Normal dictionaries don't. If you look at **doc** of `fromkeys`, you find:

> OD.fromkeys(S[, v]) -> New ordered dictionary with keys from S.

So the `fromkeys` class method, creates an `OrderedDict` using items in the input iterable S (in my example characters from a string) as keys. In a dictionary, keys are unique, so duplicate items in `S` are ignored.

For example:

```
s = "abbcdece" # example string with duplicate characters

print(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s))
```

This results in an OrderedDict:

```
OrderedDict([('a', None), ('b', None), ('c', None), ('d', None), ('e', None)])
```

Then `" ".join(some_iterable)` takes an iterable and joins its elements using a space in this case. It uses only keys, as iterating through a dictionary is done by its keys. For example:

```
for k in OrderedDict.fromkeys(s): # k is a key of the OrderedDict
    print(k)
```

Results in:

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Subsequently, call to join:

```
print(" ".join(OrderedDict.fromkeys(s)))
```

will print out:

```
a b c d e
```

**Using set**

Sometimes, people use a set for this:

```
print( " ".join(set(s)))
# c a b d e
```

But unlike sets in C++, sets in python do not guarantee order. So using a set will give you unique values easily, but they might be in a different order then they are in the original list or string (as in the above example).

Hope this helps a bit.

Answer (score 1):

By list comprehension

```
print ' '.join([character for index, character in enumerate(foo) if character not in foo[:index]])
```

Comment: creating all those `foo[:index]` is not very efficient - let alone scanning each one with `in`

Comment: You don't seem to get the question at all... He is asking how his code works. He doesn't need nor want an alternate solution.